# Why does "go list -m all" command list some unused module in my project?

Tags: go, go-modules

The **go list -m all** command:

```
$ go list -m all |grep rsc
rsc.io/pdf v0.1.1
rsc.io/quote/v3 v3.1.0
rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0
```

But my project does not depend on **rsc.io/sampler**

```
$ go mod why -m rsc.io/sampler
# rsc.io/sampler
(main module does not need module rsc.io/sampler)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [rcs.io/quote/v3](https://github.com/rsc/quote/blob/master/v3/quote.go) depends on it.

By pulling in a dependency, you in turn pull in all of its dependencies.

As for the `main module does not need ...` line, this is explained in the `go help mod why` help text:

> If the package or module is not referenced from the main module, the
> stanza will display a single parenthesized note indicating that fact.

When the information from `go mod why` seems incomplete, try `go mod graph` for the full dependency graph.

Comment: But #go mod why# command tells does not need the module，what's the reason?

Comment: Because the "main module" (your module; aka your code; aka the module you are writing) does not need `rsc.io/sampler`. **BUT**, one of the modules that your module (aka the main module) uses, `rcs.io/quote/v3`, **does** need it. It is a dependency of an dependency, that is why your module technically doesn't need it.